# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (deleted wordpress menu) PHP issue or WP issue?

Tags: php, wordpress

I deleted a menu in my WP CMS. This was a menu in the footer.

Now on my sites footer, I get this text.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/user/example.net/wp-content/themes/example/sidebar-footerfour.php on line 11
```

I tried restoring the menu but the text is still there.

Here is the code in my WP editor of `sidebarfooterfour`

```
<div class="fwidth185 lefts"><h4>UK Payday    <span> Lenders</span></h4>
    <?php $trusted_loan = wp_get_nav_menu_items('UK Payday Lenders'); $count = 1; ?>
    <ul class="loan_cat">
    <?php foreach ($trusted_loan as $menu_loan) : ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $menu_loan->url; ?>"><?php echo $menu_loan->title; ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; $trusted_loan=''; ?>
    </ul>
    <h4>Responsible      <span> Lendings</span></h4>
    <?php $trusted_loan = wp_get_nav_menu_items('Responsible Lendings'); $count = 1; ?>
    <ul class="loan_cat">
    <?php foreach ($trusted_loan as $menu_loan) : ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $menu_loan->url; ?>"><?php echo $menu_loan->title; ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I don't know code so I am not sure what to do or even whether it's a Wordpress issue or PHP issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, does the menu you're loading still exist?

Comment: Did you delete the `UK Payday Leanders` or the `Responsible Lendings` menu?

Comment: I followed Kolinks tip but i still had the header there...that's what i was orginally trying to remove. I thought i could just delete the menu in Wordpress..  

i changed it to use ?: array () and deleted lines 7 and 8. (The header and wp_get_nav_menu_items ('Resonsible Lending') 



This is kind of fun. Testing code to see what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup of your file.  After that clear the file and add the following:

```
<div class="fwidth185 lefts">
    <h4>UK Payday    <span> Lenders</span></h4>
    <?php $trusted_loan = wp_get_nav_menu_items('UK Payday Lenders'); $count = 1; ?>
    <ul class="loan_cat">
    <?php foreach ($trusted_loan as $menu_loan) : ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $menu_loan->url; ?>"><?php echo $menu_loan->title; ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; $trusted_loan=''; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This will get rid of the error and remove any leftover HTML associated with the menu you have deleted.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of just using `foreach($trusted_loan as $menu_loan)`, try using this contruct instead:

```
foreach($trusted_loan ?: array() as $menu_loan)
```

(Or, of you have PHP 5.4 or greater, use `$trustedload?:[]`)

This will ensure that if `$trusted_loan` is not set or otherwise falsy, you will be using an array and avoiding the error.

Comment: While this gets rid of the error it really only hides the problem.